# Unit Testing contents of error message?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I have a class that raises an event with an error message.

In some of my tests I am subscribing to the event and asserting that the error message is not empty.

```
[Test]
public MyMethod_DoBad_ErrorMessageNotEmpty()
{
    var logic = new MyClass();

    string ErrorMessage = String.Empty;

    logic.DisplayError += delegate(string s)
    {
         ErrorMessage = s;
    };

    logic.DoItBadly();

    Assert.IsFalse(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ErrorMessage));

}

//MyClass

public void DoItBadly()
{
  //do something naughty but not final
  DisplayError("Naughty");

  //some other problem arises
  if (1==1)
    DisplayError("Something else naughty");
}
```

However I am starting to find in edge case testing that my new tests that should fail, pass because it has raised an error event previously in the code before it has got to where I want it to.

Therefore should I be asserting that the error message contains a specified string?

Comment: It would be great if you provide some code for your test. Are your tests independent, or they share some data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should test both this cases in different tests:

```
[Test]
public ShouldRaiseNaughtyErrorWhenDoBadly()
{
    var logic = new MyClass();
    string errorMessage = String.Empty;
    logic.DisplayError += delegate(string s) {errorMessage = s; };

    logic.DoItBadly();

    Assert.That(errorMessage, Is.EqualTo("Naughty"));
}

[Test]
public ShouldRaiseElseNaughtyErrorWhenDoBadlyWithOtherProblem()
{
    var logic = new MyClass();
    string errorMessage = String.Empty;
    logic.DisplayError += delegate(string s) {errorMessage = s; };

    // do something for other problem condition
    logic.DoItBadly();

    Assert.That(errorMessage, Is.EqualTo("Something else naughty"));
}
```

Or, if you need to check both errors where raised:

```
[Test]
public ShouldRaiseBothErrors()
{
    var logic = new MyClass();
    List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();
    logic.DisplayError += delegate(string s) {errorMessages.Add(s); };

    // do something for other problem condition
    logic.DoItBadly();

    Assert.That(errorMessages.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));
    Assert.That(errorMessages[0], Is.EqualTo("Naughty"));
    Assert.That(errorMessages[1], Is.EqualTo("Something else naughty"));
}
```

UPDATE:
Considering event-based nature of your notifications, you can catch them all and then search for some concrete error:

```
[Test]
public ShouldRaiseNaughtyErrorWhenDoBadly()
{
    var logic = new MyClass();
    List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();
    logic.DisplayError += delegate(string s) { errorMessages.Add(s); };    

    logic.DoItBadly();

    Assert.That(errorMessages.Contains("Naughty"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> However I am starting to find in edge case testing that my new tests that should fail, pass because it has raised an error event previously in the code before it has got to where I want it to.

That suggests you're either reusing an existing object between tests, or that your test is doing too much. If you can't help but do work before the *real* operation you want to test, you can write your test as:

```
// Construct objects
// Do setup work
// Check that there's no error message yet

// Do work you expect to fail
// Check that there *is* an error message
```

Of course you *can* check for the exact error message, but that's likely to end up being time-consuming. If you're using reasonably ad-hoc error reporting (not worrying about i18n etc) then I'd personally just check whether *an* error message is present or not.

Comment: The issue is that my ErrorMessage variable is populated by a error event that happened in DoItBadly before it got to the line of code I want it to test. Its not reusing anything. Its just that line 10 raises an error event but I want to test line 20 also raises the event

Comment: @Jon: Right, so as I said, check that it's empty *just before* line 20. If you're expecting there to be an error before, you'll need to clear it before you call the method you really want to test.

Comment: Its one method under test which is the problem

Comment: Maybe you need to refactor if you want to test both bits of functionality.

Comment: @Jon: As far as the calling code is concerned, something went wrong in `DoItBadly`. You *could* check for the expected *number* of errors by adding to a `List<string>` within your event handler, if that would help... (Or just increment an integer if you don't need to look at the message itself.)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would want to isolate and abstract the areas of DoItBadly() that are polluting your error text with the error message, so that you can test the rest of the method without problem.

However, given the understanding that it can often be easier said than done, the next best thing would be to only populate ErrorMessage with s if a certain condition is met (or have a whitelist of error messages that would not populate ErrorMessage). So if you only set ErrorMessage if it is not the error you have deemed "acceptable," then your test should pass and your own requirement should be met.

Though even better would be to assert a positive outcome, instead of making your success case the absence of negative outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

The error message itself should be pushed somewhere reusable so that the test can refer to it too.

This way you aren't asserting the text of the error message itself, only that the correct error message was used, whatever its text is.

```
public static class ErrorMessages {
   public const string Naughty = "Naughty";
   public const string Naughty2 = "Something else naughty";
}

...

public void DoItBadly() {
  //do something naughty but not final
  DisplayError(ErrorMessages.Naughty);

  //some other problem arises
  if (1==1)
    DisplayError(ErrorMessages.Naughty2);
}

...

[Test]
public MyMethod_DoBad_NaughtyErrorMessage() {
   // cause Naughty error

   Assert.AreEqual(ErrorMessages.Naughty, ErrorMessage);
}

[Test]
public MyMethod_DoBad_Naughty2ErrorMessage
   // cause Naughty2 error

   Assert.AreEqual(ErrorMessages.Naughty2, ErrorMessage);
}
```